# Load 2 svg files in snap.svg with a onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, svg, snap.svg

At the moment i am loading up 1 SVG File with snap.svg and i manipulate it a little bit.
But now I want to open up another SVG File when i click on a rectangle in my already loaded SVG file. Is that possible if yes how?

Tried some different onclick stuff but it never worked

As showed down below in the code this is how i wana load up the SVG file btw. the other svg file that is already loaded up should disapear and only the svg file that gets loaded with the onclick function should be there to see

```
myelement.onclick(function() {
Snap.load("2ndsvg.svg");
});
```

Hope you can help me thanks